# unable to Filter empty value using Angular Material using mat-chip

Tags: angular, angular-material

1. I am unable to filter empty values in my .ts file  due to some restrictions
2. i have  tried the following method to not to show empty chip

   ```
   <mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [selectable]="selectable"
                 [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(fruit)">
          <p *ngIf="fruit.name">{{fruit.name}}</p>
          <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
        </mat-chip>
   ```

   [image: i am still seeing my empty tag]

3)the following is my fruits object

```
  fruits: Fruit[] = [
    { name: "Lemon" },
    { name: "Lime" },
    { name: "Apple" },
    { name: "" }
  ];
```

Comment: if you can't filter in ts, you can filter in *ngFor with filter function.

Comment: Thanks @tmsbrndz i am trying with custim filter  if it works i will post my answer

Answer (score -1):

Your condition is wrong in:

```
<p *ngIf="fruit.name">{{fruit.name}}</p>
```

Use:

```
<p *ngIf="fruit.name !== ''">{{fruit.name}}</p>
```

or

```
<p *ngIf="!!fruit.name">{{fruit.name}}</p>
```